# Lens/Mirror system for stereo photography?

Tags: optics, accessories, stereoscopy

I am interested in exploring the viability of doing stereophotography using a single camera.

The idea is that the camera would take images in pairs, first using one side of the lens system, then using the other. (obviously this would require some kind of mechanism to switch between the two sides)

Are there standard lens or rather mirror systems for doing this?

(The cited answer is different than my question because that poster is trying to capture two images in a single exposure, whereas my case is two different exposures.)

Comment: You will run into problems when not capturing the images simultaneously.

Comment: @scottbb The same question is relevant to stereo photography. Do you consider stereo photography off topic? Also, how is photogrammetry not about photography. The instrument in photogrammetry is a CAMERA.

Comment: @Tyler Durden and all that is just Physics, so why not ask all questions there? The answer is because the more specialised sites provide better answers dedicated to their fields. And the gis site is explicitly about photogrammetry. Stereo photography is also not exactly a big thing in photography, while stereophotogrammetry definitely is a big thing in photogrammetry. This is not so much about relevance or on/off-topicness, but where you are most likely to find the best answers to your question.

Comment: @null This has nothing to do with physics. They would tell me to post it on photography. This is a question about special accessories for cameras. That is a photography question.

Comment: I changed the question to eliminate the photogrammetry aspect.

Comment: "*This has nothing to do with physics.*" Turns out that optics *is* a field of physics, which this is all based on. "*They would tell me to post it on photography*" and why exactly would you listen to them and not us? Again, [gis.se] is **explicitly about photogrammetry** this is where the experienced people are. Is it so important to you to win the argument about where your question belongs that you dismiss that?

Comment: Suggestion: GoPros are not specifically off-topic here, especially in the context of still photos. Knowing your ultimate application, you might want to put those details back into the question (GoPro, ~ 250g weight limit). Otherwise, you are likely to get answers about _much_ heavier solutions (if they exist).

Comment: There is a Panasonic 3D lens for Micro 4/3. Though it seems its not great quality, limited resolution, and doesn't work for video. http://www.four-thirds.org/en/microft/other.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better to use : Mirror or totally reflecting prism?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60764/which-is-better-to-use-mirror-or-totally-reflecting-prism)

Comment: Sure you could build some fancy rig with a fast-moving flip mirror, but the spatial separation required to get useable stereoscopic effect would make the thing unwieldy.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there standard lens or rather mirror systems for doing this?

There are stereoscopic lenses that let you take a single exposure with right and left images at once. One example is the Loreo stereoscopic lens:

[image: Loreo 9005]

There are many other similar devices that are or were made for a variety of cameras.

I'm not aware of an optical attachment that lets you take the two images separately, probably because capturing the images at two different times, even if they're close together, will always be a problem if there's any movement in the scene at all. It's very hard to get even a tree to stay completely still for the second or two that you might have between shots if you were working quickly -- the wind might blow the leaves, or a cloud might move and change the lighting. Animals, including people, would be impossible.

If you're aware of the possible problems and still want to experiment, my advice would be to move the entire camera from one position to the other. You could easily build a fixture for a tripod that lets you slide the camera between two positions. Find a short piece of appropriate straight metal stock ([80/20 t-slotted extrusion](https://www.8020.net) would be perfect) and something that slides along it to which you can attach the camera (80/20 makes a variety of linear slides that fit their extrusions). Put stops at each end to establish the two positions, and then you'll be able to quickly and easily take photos in the same direction from two positions a fixed distance apart.

Answer (score 0):

Try a google search and you will find something like this:

http://www.provideocoalition.com/gopro-dual-hero-3d/

In this solution you have two cameras put together side by side.

https://www.google.com/search?q=stereoscopic+gopro

---

If you are more specific on your google search

https://www.google.com/search?q=stereoscopic+gopro

You find a lens for stereoscopic images, for example:

http://www.vitrima.com/

Whith the current trend of the use of google Cardboard VR https://vr.google.com/cardboard/ you have some options.